# Post and download in the same button click?

Tags: php, jquery, csv

Is it possible to POST using AJAX and then force download with the response when successful?

My code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#CSV", function () {

    var csv_value = $('#result').table2CSV({
        delivery: 'value'
    });
    console.log(csv_value);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "csv.php",
        data: {
            csv: csv_value
        },
        success: function (html) {
          //Download
        }
    });

});
```

As you can see i'm converting my `HTML` table to `CSV` then posting it to my `php` file where I want to generate a `.csv` file as this is not possible using JS.

php script.

```
$file = $_POST['csv'];
$filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
$csv_output=stripcslashes($_POST['csv']);
print $csv_output;
exit;
```

Can I initiate a download from my success function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to redirect the user to the download page, something like this:

```
success: function (html) {
  window.location.href = "your/download/path/file.php";
}
```

In this file, you prepare the download.